# How to clean all the setInterval before disconnecting

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am looking for a way to clean all the intervals before logout, I have several intervals in different pages. When I disconnect the intervals keep spinning. Thank

```
  ngOnInit() {
    var firstInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.get();
      console.log("ok");
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: `clearInterval(firstInterval)` ?

Comment: Why not use RxJS and its equivalent `interal`? You could compose `Subscription`s into a single `Subscription` and `unsubscribe()` from all of them in a single call on the composed `Subscription`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will dig on this side I do not know the equivalent at all

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you for your answer, I need to do it in another view

Comment: Then you will have to store the id of the interval in some global state of your app which can be accessed by all views

Comment: @derpirscher that's exactly what i wanted to do it works fine thanks. However, when I connect after the clearInterval the setInterval does not restart.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not restart". `onNgInit()` is -- as the name and the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) suggest -- only called once when a component is initialized. So if you want to create a new interval, you'll have to create it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the life cycle hook `ngOnDestroy()`

> #### ngOnDestroy
>
> Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive or component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks. See details in Cleaning up on instance destruction in this document.

```
const firstInterval: Number;
// ...
ngOnInit() {
    this.firstInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.get();
      console.log("ok");
  }, 2000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.firstInterval) {
    clearInterval(this.firstInterval);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try this right away

Comment: Its not working for me the destruction must happen in another view where there is the connection function